# how do they do it?

Tags: security, web

i am a senior developer and I'm trying to advance my knowledge of security to a deeper level. That is to say that i know what these hackers can do/what the risks are, but I'd like to know how they do it in general. On that note, if anyone can enlighten me on the following items, i would be most grateful:

1. Packet sniffing: I know that packets can be sniffed out and analyzed, but how do they do it? my understanding was that in order to do this, there would need to be actual software running on the server itself since it needs access to the network card to do so... is that accurate? If not, how can they remotely capture incoming packets to a server without access to that box directly?
2. Session Hijacking: Once again, i am confused here. I know they can do it, but how? The session ID is issues by the server itself, and then returned to the browser based on what? the caller's ip address? mac address? what is used by these hackers to capture the session id from a web session? is it software on a pc that is infected?
3. Site Hijacking: again, i know they can do this, but from my current knowledge, this would mean that they would have to have hijacked/infected a DNS publishing server and redirecting queries for that site to their choice of IP address... again: is that accurate?
4. Hijacking a server: how is this possible? how can an open port, for example, allow any hacker to gain full fledged access yo a box so that they can infect it or install some piece of software that would enable 1, 2 and 3 above? My current understanding is that ports are used to communicate, but that unless some software/service is monitoring that port and waiting for commands, nothing would come of that port being open... is that accurate? and if so, why is so much importance given to ports being closed and such?
5. Hijacking some super secure site: i work every day with security in mind, and constantly use things like: SSL, RSA, SHA512, SSL TOKENS, IP restriction, etc... my question is: how in the crapper are they STILL able to get in with all of these things enabled?

i know that's a lot of stuff, but i really am curious and want to take my security knowledge to the next level. If you're a developer with the same mindset as me, you have issues just using some pre-built library or control without knowing what it does in the background in details, and you'll understand why I'm not happy just knowing which protocols, libraries or encryption methods to implement.

Know the enemy, right?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better fit for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I love hacking (only for good), and I think the more people are educated about it the safer we all will be, so I applaud you for your curiosity.

These are great questions, but a good answer would literally require an entire book or two.  I have read all of these books in my studies and I personally recommend them.  I recommend the following to get you started:

This will get you started with basic tools and techniques.  This book doesn't go very deep so if you're looking for the meat, skip it and read the other three unless you are very new to security:  [The Basics of Hacking and Penetration Testing: Ethical Hacking and Penetration Testing Made Easy, Patrick Engebretson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597496553) (Full disclosure, the author was a professor of mine at DSU.  The book rocks though)

For a relatively deep introduction to security, including an excellent background in OSes and networking:[Counter Hack Reloaded: A Step-by-Step Guide to Computer Attacks and Effective Defenses (2nd Edition), Edward Skoudis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131481045) (probably my favorite book of all time)

To dive very deep (Assembly language level) into how the attacks work:[Hacking, The Art of Exploitation, Jon Erickson](http://nostarch.com/hacking2.htm)

To dive deeply into the Web app side of things:[The Web Application Hacker's Handbook: Finding and Exploiting Security Flaws, Dafydd Stuttard, Marcus Pinto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026470) (Full disclosure, the technical editor was a professor of mine at DSU)

Comment: thank you for the book references! now i have somewhere to start getting the info i'm looking for :-)